Validity of some complex life surviving after the planet's atmosphere suddenly gets chlorine in it
I have this planet that used to be earth-like, but due to some sudden volcanism, this planet's atmosphere now has 1% chlorine in it. It is fine if most life dies, but is it possible for some plants and animals to survive this gas chamber of a planet?

1% of the atmosphere would translate to a tiny fraction of a percent of the ocean's water. Are you counting deep-ocean vents. What counts as complex life? The shrimps and tubeworms at those vents or not?

Straight answer:
Basically no.
Leaving aside whether it's plausible to have such eruptions: having many species distant from the eruptions survive an initially 1% chlorine atmosphere would be reasonable. They just have to survive a few horrifically destructive rounds of acid rain and a long term slight acidification of the oceans and water table.
However, if you're maintaining a 1% chlorine atmosphere, you have to do it by pumping in a huge excess of Chlorine. The chlorine won't stay in the atmosphere at first. Chlorine bonds aggressively with all kinds of chemicals and does all kinds of downstream chemistry. You'll have to continuously replenish the chlorine until the whole exposed crust of the planet is full of chlorine mineral compounds, all the oceans are full of aqueous hydrochloric acid and chlorine oxides, the air is full of higher volatility chlorine oxides, etc.
It's sort of like asking if any animals would survive in a zoo filled with 1% live hand grenades. Maybe at first, but you have to keep adding hand grenades...
Frame Challenge answer:
You cannot have a single-point-of-departure alternate history that adds a large quantity of a specific reactive substance like chlorine. The second you do that, your story becomes a story about a complex multi-variable chemical reaction, not characters solving problems in an environment.
In the unlikely event that your story is in fact about chemists solving chemistry problems having to do with a complex multi-variable chemical reaction, you're going to have to be a chemist or get a chemist cowriter to write it.
If your story isn't about chemists solving chemistry problems, the chemistry is irrelevant anyway. So your atmosphere didn't suddenly become "1% chlorine", it suddenly became "choked with toxic gasses and poisoned ash" and then you write a story about whatever you want. The tiny fraction of your readers who are chemists or geologists will know a plausible way for that to happen and decide that that's what you meant; the rest of them won't care.

This is an important aspect of worldbuilding despite it being storybuilding advice: Some aspects of one's worldbuilding serve the purpose of setting up the story one really wants to tell. Like time travel setting up the victorian romance with a touch of A Connecticut Yankee in King Arthur's Court. The time travel isn't the point of the story. It's not even a significant portion of the worldbuildiing. But when done well, it sets up the emotion of the whole story. Unless the chlorine is an imporant part of the story, it's just the foil that triggers the story one really wants to tell.

Regarding the "informed readers" leaving it open is even better because they won't find holes in the details but will instead fill them in as they see realistic
